# php redirection after execution of contact form code

Tags: php, paypal, contact-form, payflowpro

Friends..!

I want to redirect after some seconds to paypal payflow link as:

> https://pilot-payflowlink.paypal.com/?MODE=TEST&SECURETOKENID=f976bec739fb40a5a0e48c1876d570e6&SECURETOKEN=7yVdfkdwbgkOzAg2h1vxHggvL

after entering details in contact form and clicking on send and then showing Email Sent Successfully etc..as

the contact form processer code is as follows :

```
<?php
$cardlink = $_POST['cardlink'];
$howmuch = $_POST['howmuch'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$website = $_POST['website'];
$comments = $_POST['comments'];
$formcontent="Card Image Link: $cardlink \n How much cards: $howmuch \n From: $name \n Email: $email \n Address: $address \n Phone: $phone \n Website: $website \n Additinal Informations: $comments";
$recipient = "nicefellow1234@gmail.com";
$subject = "Card Designig Order By : $name ";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
// Email has sent successfully, echo a success page.
 echo "<fieldset>";
 echo "<div id='success_page'>";
 echo "<h1>Email Sent Successfully.</h1>";
 echo "<p>Thank you <strong>$name</strong>, your message has been submitted to us.</p>";
 echo "</div>";
 echo "</fieldset>";
?>
```

and the live contact form is at this link : http://www.webngraphicssolutions.com/new_site/html_purple/web-contact-form-order-now/index.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use javascript to redirect the user when the form has been submitted.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function () {
    window.location.href = "https://pilot-payflowlink.paypal.com/?MODE=TEST&SECURETOKENID=f976bec739fb40a5a0e48c1876d570e6&SECURETOKEN=7yVdfkdwbgkOzAg2h1vxHggvL";
  };
</script>
```

Output the above code in your response sent by the form processor.

**Edit:**
Since the form is ajax based and you want to redirect after 5 seconds, here is the modified answer:

Put the below code in your ajax success handler.

```
window.setTimeout(function () {
  window.location.href = "https://pilot-payflowlink.paypal.com/?MODE=TEST&SECURETOKENID=f976bec739fb40a5a0e48c1876d570e6&SECURETOKEN=7yVdfkdwbgkOzAg2h1vxHggvL";
}, 5000);
```

Comment: but i want to redirect after 5 seconds..! and also the form is ajax based..so it doesn't load when the Email Sent Successfully appear after clicking on send i mean after subimitting so will it work with window.load function in javascript..

Comment: for further checking please check it live at this link you will know that it don't load on submision : http://www.webngraphicssolutions.com/new_site/html_purple/web-contact-form-order-now/index.php

Comment: Modified my answer accordingly.

Comment: i added that code to my one js file namely as  `jquery.jigowatt.js`

Comment: but now when the contact form loads so without even filling form after 5 seconds it redirects to that url but i want it to be like that filling form then submitting form and Email Sent Successfly Shown and then after 5 seconds it will redirect to the url..

Comment: Thanks..for your time..friend..i did that...and it's working now..!

Answer (score -1):

Use setInterval Function

```
setInterval(function(){
    // Do something every 2 seconds
}, 2000);
```